# Parsing Date Time string produces unexpected results

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert a string which is in the correct format into a date of exactly the same format for a linq query to work against a SQL date.

I've tried several conversion methods but all have failed. The example below shows the issue:

```
var test = DateTime.ParseExact("2019-04-09 13:15:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null);
```

produces

```
{09/04/2019 13:15:00}
```

I have no idea why the date comes out like this but I would like to come out like:

```
2019-04-09 13:15:00
```

I tried with culture info but no luck. Not sure why this happening?

Comment: thats just the debugger view. internally it has the right values.

Comment: `DateTime` has no format, they are binary values. If you check [check the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,140) you'll see that `DateTime` actually stores a 64-bit tick count. What you see is how a client (the debugger, a desktop application, a web page) formats the date for display. This depends on the user's locale, or an explicit locale set at the application or page level

Comment: You should never set the last parameter to null, because this will use the users current culture and thus this method may behave differently for different users and can throw an exception. Always provide a culture - most often `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to produce reproducible results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You parse the date in the correct format, so that's fine. The DateTime-object contains the correct value, so you can use it for your database.

If you want to see it in your prefered format you also need to output it using the same format, otherwise the default format of your user account (or in case of a web request the preferred language of the calling browser) will be used for displaying it.

```
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

If you are using Visual Studio, you can execute this command in the "Immediate Window" while running the debugger:

```
test.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

In other windows the debugger will use the default output format like described above.

Comment: The default format is the *user's locale*, not the system locale. More specifically, it's the `Thread.CurrentCulture` which defaults to the user's locale for desktop apps, the browser's preferred language for web apps

Answer (score 3):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how DateTime values work. They do not have any human-readable format. Rather, they are stored as a binary value that is not human readable. The format you're seeing is something provided as a convenience by your debugger.

If you need a different specific format for anything other than use in SQL*, you can call `ToString()` with the appropriate format string. Just remember when you do that you are no longer working with a DateTime value, but are back to using a string again, and the best practice is to wait as long as possible before going back to strings.

---

<sup>*For SQL, you should be using parameterized queries, where there is a placeholder in the query and your datetime value is assigned directly to the parameter value without converting to a string first.</sup>